# Hibernate Duplicate Rows in Many-to-Many XML Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate

I tried all the possible solution in stackoverflow. This is my XML:

Role.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Role" table="T_ROLE"   dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.String"  column="ROLE_ID" length="32">
        <generator class="uuid.hex" />
    </id>
    <property       name="roleName"         column="ROLENAME"           type="string"   length="50"     not-null="true" />
    <property       name="description"      column="DESCN"              type="string"   length="255"    not-null="false" />
    <property       name="createDatetime"   column="CREATE_DATETIME"    type="timestamp"/>
    <property       name="updateDatetime"   column="UPDATE_DATETIME"    type="timestamp"  />

    <set name="permissionSet" table="T_ROLE_PERM" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all"  >
        <key>
            <column name="ROLE_ID" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many column="PERMISSION_ID" class="Permission" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Permission.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Permission" table="T_PERMISSION">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.String" column="PERMISSION_ID" length="32">
        <generator class="uuid.hex" />
    </id>
    <property       name="name"             column="PERMNAME"           type="string"       not-null="true"     length="50" />
    <property       name="type"             column="TYPE"               type="string"       not-null="true"     length="20" />
    <property       name="description"      column="DESCN"              type="string"       not-null="false"    length="255"/>
    <property       name="createDatetime"   column="CREATE_DATETIME"    type="timestamp"/>
    <property       name="updateDatetime"   column="UPDATE_DATETIME"    type="timestamp"  />

    <set name="roleSet" table="T_ROLE_PERM" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" >
        <key>
            <column name="PERMISSION_ID" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="Role" column="ROLE_ID"/>          
    </set>

</class>
```

Initializer.Java:

```
public class Initializer {

private PermissionDao permissionDao;

@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;

public PermissionDao getPermissionDao() {
    return permissionDao;
}

public void setPermissionDao(PermissionDao permissionDao) {
    System.out.println("PerDAO set for Initializer");
    this.permissionDao = permissionDao;
}

public void initMethod() {
    System.out.println("Initializer called");
    initRolePerm();
    System.out.println("Initializer done");
}

private void initRolePerm(){
    Permission deletePermission = new Permission();
    deletePermission.setName("ABC");
    deletePermission.setType("ABC");

    Permission postPermission = new Permission();
    postPermission.setName("XYZ");
    postPermission.setType("XYZ");

    Role adminRole = new Role();
    adminRole.setRoleName("Admin");

    adminRole.getPermissionSet().add(postPermission);
    adminRole.getPermissionSet().add(deletePermission);
    permissionDao.insert(postPermission);
    permissionDao.insert(deletePermission);

    adminRole.getPermissionSet().add(postPermission);
    adminRole.getPermissionSet().add(deletePermission);

    roleDao.insert(adminRole);
}
}
```

Not sure how there are duplicates that are getting inserted into the table here. I run this initializer when the tomcat starts up. When I check the db there is exactly one duplicate for each of the row in T_ROLE, T_PERMISSION and eventually in T_ROLE_PERM. I am not able to figure out where the second row is being inserted from. TIA.

Comment: I guess you should give inverse=true in role Entity and inverse=false in permission entity.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you gave inverse=false in role entity ?

Comment: @Ramesh tried both ways. It was not the issue.

Comment: posted answer . It might solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You have given **Cascade All** in Role Entity . Saving role entity will save permission entity also .

Ref [Cascade](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades)

Just Remove these lines and save only role Entity

```
permissionDao.insert(postPermission);
permissionDao.insert(deletePermission);
```

Add role references in Permission

```
 postPermission.getRoleSet().add(adminRole);
 deletePermission.getRoleSet().add(adminRole);
```

Modify method as

```
private void initRolePerm(){
   Permission deletePermission = new Permission();
   deletePermission.setName("ABC");
   deletePermission.setType("ABC");

   Permission postPermission = new Permission();
   postPermission.setName("XYZ");
   postPermission.setType("XYZ");

   Role adminRole = new Role();
   adminRole.setRoleName("Admin");

  postPermission.getRoleSet().add(adminRole);
  deletePermission.getRoleSet().add(adminRole);
  adminRole.getPermissionSet().add(postPermission);
  adminRole.getPermissionSet().add(deletePermission);

  roleDao.insert(adminRole);
 }
```

Change inverse also

inverse=true in role Entity and inverse=false in permission entity